# Does the maximum cut implies the minimum flow?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, network-flow

Is it possible to reverse the result of the min-cut max-flow theorem and obtain the result that if you have the maximum cut, then you have the minimum flow? I've been thinking about it, but I have no clue if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. These are dual problems. Note that the max-flow problem can be formulated as a Linear Program. So the Max-Flow Min-Cut Theorem follows from LP duality.